# Correct syntax of executing a function on page load and on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute the function `wow_delay()` on page load and then on the resize event. My code does what I expect, I just want to know if there is a more correct syntax of doing this.

```
(function($) {

  function wow_delay() {

    if( $(window).width() < 768 ){

        $('.wow').attr('data-wow-delay', 0);

    }

  }

  wow_delay();

  $(window).resize(function() {

    wow_delay();

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `$(window).resize(wow_delay);`

Comment: `$(window).on('load resize', wow_delay);` I'm assuming that "page load" is the window's load event and not document ready.

Comment: you may want to consider using a debounce/throttler on any function that calls on resize (can trigger very quickly on some browsers). I highly recommend Ben Almans http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/